# Connection to postgresql on android studio fails: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

I'm developing an app in Android Studio and it always fails to access the database, I've already added the necessary dependencies and permissions but it always generates the error: ***Something unusual has occurred to *cause* the *driver* to *fail*. *Please report* this exception.**

I tried accessing it in a separate Kotlin script and it works perfectly, but any attempt to access it with the app generates this error.

Kt file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.cadastrar)
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.status)

        button.setOnClickListener {
        text.text = verificarSorteio("11111111111")
        }
    }


    fun verificarSorteio(cpf:String):String{
        try{
            val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://isabelle.db.elephantsql.com:5432/database",
                "user",
                "password"
            )
            connection.close()
            return "Accept"
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            return "$e"
        }
    }


}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.23")
    ...
}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: When they say "please report this exception", they don't mean "write to Stackoverflow about it", but "this is a problem with the code that should not happen; please tell the authors of the software". You should report it as a bug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.